# Making a basic functions fails

Tags: javascript, function

Okay, thanks for the help I already got. Stupid spelling mistake.
I tried to rewrite the code, but it still doesn't work.

This is my code that works perfect:

```
if (obj != "finished") {
 var cmd = "finished = ("+obj+"== target3)";
 ggbApplet.debug(cmd); 
 ggbApplet.setErrorDialogsActive(false);
 ggbApplet.evalCommand(cmd);
 finished = ggbApplet.getValueString("finished");
 if (finished.indexOf("true") > -1) {
   ggbApplet.setVisible("step3",true);
 }
}
```

If I replace the code for this one, it doesn't work anymore.

```
function checkpoint(target,step){
if (obj != "finished") {
 var cmd = "finished = ("+obj+"== "+target+")";
 ggbApplet.debug(cmd); 
 ggbApplet.setErrorDialogsActive(false);
 ggbApplet.evalCommand(cmd);
 finished = ggbApplet.getValueString("finished");
 if (finished.indexOf("true") > -1) {
   ggbApplet.setVisible(step,true);
 }
}
}

checkpoint(target3,step3);
```

I really don't see what I'm doign wrong. obj is something that is defined somehwere else in the code. But I don't thing that is causing problems, as everything works perfect before I tried to write it as an function. Any further help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please add detail when you say "it doesn't work". What happened?

Comment: Perhaps ´checpoint´ and ´checkpoint´

Comment: In the function, you haven't declared `obj`. If this is an object outside of the function that you would like to use, pass it in.

Comment: What do you think is the relationship between `step` in the parameter list and `"step"` in the body of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is defined fine, apart from a possible spelling mistake in its name, but the use of the parameters is incorrect. You're passing in `target` and `step` as `parameters` but then not using those variables but using `strings` instead.

```
ggbApplet.setVisible("step",true);
```

should be

```
ggbApplet.setVisible(step, true);
```

and

```
var cmd = "finished = ("+obj+"== target)";
```

should be:

```
var cmd = "finished = ("+obj+"== " + target + ")";
```

This way you can pass in the strings of the target and the step and they should evaluate correctly.

There may be other issues with scoping and global variables, but its not possible to tell from this small snippet of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it stil l fails to work. If you have time to look at my new code, I would really appreciated it ! I've edited the question.

Comment: Another issue is that when you are calling the function you need to pass the parameters in as strings. Try: checkpoint("target3","step3");

Comment: ok that was a little bit too much maybe :P but really appreacited your help, spend hours on this

Answer (score 1):

You have two different spellings:

```
function checpoint()
```

and

```
checkpoint(target, step1);
```

Also, is `obj` a global variable?  I don't see where it's defined or passed to the function.

In addition, you should look in the browser error console to see what errors are reported there. That is the first place you should look when things aren't working as it will tell you about undefined variables, exceptions thrown, etc...